# Spring MVC @Pathvariable won't work

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have an interface and an implementation class:

**Interface**

```
@RequestMapping(value = CUSTOMER_PATH + "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + CHARSET_UTF_8_ENCODING})
    Response getCustomerDetails(@PathVariable(CONTACT_ID) String id);
```

**Impl**

```
@Override
public Response getCustomerDetails(String id) {
    String methodname = "getCustomerDetails: ";
    LOG.info(methodname + "Get Customer Details");

    Response response;
    System.out.println("******************id: " + id);

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
        response = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(MockData.customerDetailsInvalid).build();
        LOG.info(methodname + "Returning Customer's Details - Status: Invalid Request");
    } else {
        response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(MockData.customerDetails).build();
        LOG.info(methodname + "Returning Customer's Details - Status: OK");

    }

    return response;
}
```

The path ..../MockDataProvider-war/services/mock/customers/**7** returns “invalid request”. 
The value for id is printed out as null, even though it should be 7.

Anyone know why ***id*** is null?

Comment: Try this `@PathVariable("id")` or `@PathVariable(value="id")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the Interface from:

```
Response getCustomerDetails(@PathVariable(CONTACT_ID) String id);
```

to:

```
Response getCustomerDetails(String id);
```

and the Impl from:

```
public Response getCustomerDetails(String id)
```

to

```
public Response getCustomerDetails(@PathVariable(CONTACT_ID) String id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason is `@PathVariable(CONTACT_ID)`
it should be `@PathVariable String id` this will work.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work.
I changed the Impl class to this: public Response getCustomerDetails(@PathVariable(CONTACT_ID) String id)  and  changed the interface to: Response getCustomerDetails(String id), that fixed it